# How to filter rows with minimum date value within groups?

Tags: sql

I have the following table `INPUT`:

| ID | DATE | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 884 | 2017-03-16 06:08:40 | B |
| 857 | 2017-03-24 07:14:29 | A |
| 857 | 2017-06-24 12:15:29 | A |
| 884 | 2017-10-05 00:33:08 | A |
| 255 | 2019-08-02 02:47:22 | B |

And I need to keep the first event for each ID and its TYPE in a `OUTPUT` table:

| ID | DATE | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 884 | 2017-03-16 06:08:40 | B |
| 857 | 2017-03-24 07:14:29 | A |
| 255 | 2019-08-02 02:47:22 | B |

I have tried to use a group by construct :

```
create OUTPUT as
select ID, min(DATE) as DATE, TYPE
from INPUT
group by ID
```

But I got: `not a group by expression` from the `TYPE` field.

How to keep the good value for the `TYPE`field?

Comment: Do you want the First Value encountered within each ID in your data or the rows with Min(Date) within each ID?

Comment: The proper row with min(date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can use this as a template

```
drop table if exists #have;

create table #have
(
  ID     [int]
, date   [datetime]
, type   [varchar](10)
)
;

insert into #have
values
  (884, '2017-03-16 06:08:40', 'B')
, (857, '2017-03-24 07:14:29', 'A')
, (857, '2017-06-24 12:15:29', 'A')
, (884, '2017-10-05 00:33:08', 'A')
, (255, '2019-08-02 02:47:22', 'B')
;

select * from #have;

SELECT a.*     
FROM #have a inner join
(
    SELECT id, MIN(date) AS date
    FROM #have
    GROUP BY id
) b ON a.id = b.id and a.date = b.date
```